# UHF (868 MHz) RFID external antenna

Tags: antenna, rfid

I want to find an external antenna, to remove the box and just solder directly
to actual reader board with a built-in PCB CROSS DIPOLE ANTENNA- see those 4 points in the attached image.

I want to improve the gain by that. Is that possible? How? And what e.g. antenna to use to solder it to those 4 points?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is that part after the series part (cap?) that you ask if it can be removed?  Is it an Rx/Tx switch?

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly get a small "pigtail" coax cable with an SMA cable at the end, and solder one side of the coax to your circuit, with the shield going to an appropriate ground and the center conductor to your signal. Then you could spec out a decent antenna for what you're trying to do and attach it to your SMA cable.

Though honestly I doubt it will work much better than the PCB antenna, unless you're trying to get an antenna with lots of directivity.

Comment: The RFID tag is a very small one - 2x2mm. I need to improve the gain of the current PCB antenna. Where should I solder that SMA cable? There are 4 outputs on the PCB.

Comment: break the existing connections to the antenna, and solder whereever the RFIC connects to the antenna.

Comment: Please take a look to the last picture - I need to solder directly to those 4 corners - no pigtail cable is allowed

Comment: Oof, without looking deeper, this looks like either a diversity antenna or a balanced antenna. For the former, you can solder onto one of the 4 sub antennas. If it's balanced, you're going to have a significantly larger challenge.

Comment: Added another picture :)

Comment: No idea what I'm looking at. Do you have an reverse engineered schematic

Comment: Can I solder a SMA connector as I've drawn in the last picture?

Comment: maybe. not sure what that pin is though. I'd cut the connections going to the antenna if you're gonna solder it. Also, you may not get good matching if the impedance is not 50 ohms.